# Apple push notification questions

Tags: php, ios, zend-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I don't really know how to ask these but hopefully I can make myself clear enough for you to understand my questions

1. The message limit is 256. But which is the message I need to impose this limit on?
   At first I thought it was referring to json size. But after looking through the code zend use, and others who use push notification, additional information is sent through payload (the json is 256 but the payload sent is 270). Should I limit the json to 240 or less?
2. What happens if more than one message has the same Id (I'm not talking about device id)
3. How fast can I send a second message to the same device? I have some problems that only one message arrives.

I use timestamp for Id, so I was wondering if this is the cause of my problem or maybe I can't send 5 messages in the same seccond to a single device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the 256 bytes limit is on the binary representation of the JSON payload (the device token as well as the other headers are not included in this count). That means you can send a 256 character JSON string if you only use characters which require a single byte in UTF-8 encoding. If you send text in languages whose characters require more than one byte, you will have room for less characters in your payload. I tested it, and that's how it behaves.

As for sending more than one message with the same id, that would defeat the purpose of the message id. When Apple encounter some error in your message (such as invalid device token), it sends back an error response containing the message id you supplied. If you send multiple messages with the same id, you won't be able to know which message causes the error response.

Comment: Ty, i tested the bytes limit and you are right. And i didn't knew what id is used for. But I'm using development certificate and don't seem to get errors even with an invalid token....

Comment: @ChiosaIonut Perhaps there's a problem with your error response reading code. Sometimes you might fail to read the error response (if you send many messages and only then try to read responses from the socket, the socket might be closed by Apple before you manage to read the response). To make sure you get the error response, try sending only one message with an invalid token, and then attempt to read from the input stream of the socket (with a long enough timeout).

Comment: yeah, with half of second timeout it works.But how do i check for errors then? Do i need to timeout for each message sent?

Comment: @ChiosaIonut There are suggestions how to handle it in this [Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) in the `Push Notification Throughput and Error Checking` section).

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple Developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1):

> **The Notification Payload**
>
> Each push notification includes a payload. The payload contains
> information about how the system should alert the user as well as any
> custom data you provide. The maximum size allowed for a notification
> payload is 256 bytes; Apple Push Notification Service refuses any
> notification that exceeds this limit.

The limit is on complete payload which mean JSON + Your Message. So your message should be limited to 236 characters and then add the character count of following JSON: `{"aps":{"alert":""}}`.

> how fast can i send a second message to the same device? I have some problems that only 1 message arrives.

There is no restriction on sending messages to one device. However, Apple does not guarantee delivery of all of your messages and APNS may deliver only the latest push notification message of the device in case multiple messages have been received from one app which are destined on the same device.

From [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW4):

> **Some Notifications Received, but Not All**
>
> If you are sending multiple notifications to the same device or computer within a short
> period of time, the push service will send only the last one.
>
> Here's why. The device or computer acknowledges receipt of each
> notification. Until the push service receives that acknowledgment, it
> can only assume that the device or computer has gone off-line for some
> reason and stores the notification in the quality of service (QoS)
> queue for future redelivery. The round-trip network latency here is of
> course a major factor.
>
> As described in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide, the
> QoS queue holds a single notification per app per device or computer.
> If the service receives another notification before the one in the
> queue is sent, the new notification overwrites the previous one.

<sup>Thanks to [Joachim Isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) for providing the above link.</sup>

Comment: +1 [and here's some additional docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23) on the multiple message thing.

Comment: wow, ty for your fast response, but you dind't actually answered my questions, i never asked what is the maximum size for a custom message. Along with the json message, you send extra data, like token, message length, id, expiration...I wanted to know if this is included in the 256 bytes limit

Comment: @ChiosaIonut I did answer your question that 256 bytes limit is on payload (which is also mentioned in the Apple site). Also see the [payload examples](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW15) on the same site, it shows only JSON and does not talk about token, expiration, etc.

Comment: i'm sorry, but that is what made me confused. This is what zend use: $payload = pack('CNNnH*', 1, $id, $expire, 32, $message->getToken())
        . pack('n', strlen($payload))
        . $payload;
        $ret = $this->_write($payload). I looked in some other push notification examples, and everywhere seems the same. In this case payload will have 14 more bytes

Comment: I guess so as I haven't sent push notifications using zend but I assume zend will follow apns restrictions. Have you tried sending a message with payload of 256 bytes + token? Did you receive the message?

Comment: no i didn't lol, the thought didn't even cross my mind and maybe that will be faster:), also, thx